# nested list comprehension python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a list comprehension that doubles all numbers divisible 2, triples all the numbers divisible 4 and omits all the odd numbers (for the range 1 to 100). Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, why does this need to be a list comprehension?

Comment: I wrote function and list comprehension, but want to see if it can be done just using a list comprehension

Comment: Not a real question. Not a question _at all_ actually.

Answer (score 4):

```
[x*3 if not x%4 else x*2 for x in range(2,101,2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def silly_fun(x):
    if x%4 == 0:
        return 3*x
    else:
        return 2*x

[silly_fun(y) for y in data if y%2 == 0]
```

Comment: silly fun indeed, but not really "just a list comprehension".

Comment: @Junuxx fair enough, but the question didn't say _just_ a list comprehension.  Writing it out as a function is (I feel) the moral equivalent of the folding the logic into the generator expression.  Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: OP asked for just a lc in the 3rd comment on the question, but, as I just noticed, after you  posted your answer.